# video/audio downloader and format convertor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I want to create video downloader using C#. It will download videos from youtube, metacafe and me other websites. It should be able to download audios as well. Also, It need to convert videos to different formats.

Examples are:

http://www.vso-software.fr/products/downloader/vso-downloader.php

http://xviservicethief.sourceforge.net/index.php?action=informatio

Please suggest any third party libraries that I can use or how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Friend did you got any success ? i am looking for the same. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

For Youtube, take a look at [YoutubeExtractor](http://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor)

Answer (score 0):

Since Flagbug's library is a bit dated, I've written one from the ground-up. It's called libvideo, and you can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/libvideo). Please enjoy!